# I need to remove the cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.force made in curl

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, cluster-computing, sharding

i recently made a curl  petition to  my elastic cluster to force awareness:

**cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.force**

But i didn't do it in the settings file, in a curl petition and i'm having lot's of shards unasigned. Does anybody knows the curl sentence to remove the force  awareness?

Please Help..

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good way   to revert the dynamic settings to default in elasticsearch 2.x as specified in this [github-issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/3670)

There is support for it in elasticsearch 5.x as mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/cluster-update-settings.html)

> Resetting persistent or transient settings can be done by assigning a
>   null value. If a transient setting is reset, the persistent setting is
>   applied if available. Otherwise Elasticsearch will fallback to the
>   setting defined at the configuration file or, if not existent, to the
>   default value. Here is an example:
>
> ```
> curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{
>     "transient" : {
>         "discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes" : null
>     }
> ```

In elasticsearch 2.x you have the following optoins :

- If the `cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.force` was modified in 
  `transient` settings you could restart the cluster.
- If `persistent` then the workaround is to stop the cluster delete the
  `global-X.st` files under `0/_state/`.
  Note: be careful if you go this route since you would lose all the other dynamic settings, templates too.

Comment: What's the difference between setting this awareness.force configuration in mode 'Transient' or  'Persistent'?

Comment: `Transient` would mean the dynamic settings would not persist a restart of the cluster.  `Persistent` would mean that they would presist across restarts.

Comment: sure np! whenever you get chance feel free to [upvote or accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)   if you found it helpful. thanks.

Comment: I need 15 reputation to upvote...  wait till i get 15 and i will upvote pls

Comment: i accepted the answer correctly, i didnt knew how. Thanks Keety!